# Return specific values from nested Elastic Object

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to preface this with the fact that I'm working with Elasticsearch module, which returns `elastic_transport.ObjectApiResponse`. My problem is that I need to select specific keys from this json/dictionary looking log. The indices come from different sources, and thus contain different key/value pairs. They values I need to select are `ip`, `port`, `username`, `rule_name`, `severity`, and `risk_score`. The problem is that they have different key names and each dictionary is vastly different from the other, but they all contain those values. After that, I'll throw them into a Pandas dataframe and create a table with those values. Should a value be missing, I'll fill them with a '-'.

So my question is how I can iterate over these nested objects that are neither ordered nor standardized? Any help is appreciated. Below is a sample of the data.

```
{
    'took': 11, 
    'timed_out': False, 
    '_shards': {
        'total': 17, 
        'successful': 17, 
        'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0
        }, 
    'hits': {
        'total': {'value': 58, 'relation': 'eq'}, 
        'max_score': 0.0, 
        'hits': [
            {
                '_index': '.siem-signals-default-000017', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': 'abcd1234', 
                '_score': 0.0, 
                '_source': {
                    '@timestamp': '2023-02-09T15:24:09.368Z', 
                    'process': {'pid': 668, 'executable': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\lsass.exe', 'name': 'lsass.exe'}, 
                    'ecs': {'version': '1.10.0'}, 
                    'winlog': {
                        'computer_name': 'SRVDC1', 
                        'User': 'John.Smith', 
                        'api': 'wineventlog', 
                        'keywords': ['Audit Failure']
                        },
                        'source':{'domain': 'SRVDC1', 'ip': '10.17.13.118', 'port': 42548}}
                        'rule': {'id': 'aaabbb', 'actions': [], 'interval': '2m', 'name': 'More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour '}
                        },


            {
                '_index': '.siem-signals-default-000017', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': 'abc123', 
                '_score': 0.0, 
                '_source': {
                    '@timestamp': '2023-02-09T15:24:09.369Z', 
                    'log': {'level': 'information'}, 
                    'user': {
                        'id': 'S-1-0-0', 
                        'name': 'John.Smith', 
                        'domain': 'ACME'
                        }, 
                    'related': {
                        'port': '42554', 
                        'ip': '10.17.13.118'
                        },
                    'logon': {'id': '0x3e7', 'type': 'Network', 'failure': {'sub_status': 'User logon with misspelled or bad password'}},
                    'meta': {'risk_score': 46, 'severity': 'medium'}}},

            {
                '_index': '.siem-signals-default-000017', 
                '_type': '_doc', 
                '_id': 'zzzzz', 
                '_score': 0.0, 
                '_source': {
                    'source': {
                        'port': '56489', 
                        'ip': '10.18.13.101'
                        }, 
                    'observer': {
                        'type': 'firewall', 
                        'name': 'pfSense', 
                        'serial_number': 'xoxo', 
                        'product': 'Supermicro', 
                        'ip': '10.7.3.253'
                        }, 
                    'process': {'name': 'filterlog', 'pid': '45005'}, 
                    'tags': ['firewall', 'IP_Private_Source', 'IP_Private_Destination'], 
                    'destination': {'service': 'microsoft-ds', 'port': '445', 'ip': '10.250.0.64'}, 
                    'log': {'risk_score': 73, 'severity': 'high'},
                    'rule':{'name': 'Logstash Firewall (NetBIOS and SMB Vulnerability)'}}}]}}
```

Expected Output

The sample below is possible only when the logs have the same standard structure.
[image]